# QA con IQP (ignite quality platform)

Tags: funciones

Buenas comunidad soy un QA caí en una empresa que usan un software llamado iqp, tengo problemas ya qué no hay documentación en Internet ni tampoco la empresa la tiene, es un software qué modela y automatiza test cases atravez de atributos y excepciones arma una convinatoria para tener el mayor porcentaje de cobertura, alguien lo conoce? Sabe donde buscar información? Y de lo contrario algún programa similar qué pueda sugerir?